# How to make the clang back-end of company mode in emacs support c++11?

Tags: emacs, clang

In order to make clang support c++11 standard, I must add `-std=c++11` arguments. like this,

[image]

It works well if I edit a c++ source file. But when I edit a c source file, the clang can not work. I think the reason is the arguments I added.

So how to make the clang back-end support c++11, meanwhile work well for a c source file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the option only with C++ mode, so you would do the following:

```
;;
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq company-clang-insert-arguments "-std=c++11")))
```

or somthing like that. It's not tested.